# Summarize php result

Tags: php, echo

So far i got this code:

```
function toplist() {$sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE date=curdate()";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num= mysql_numrows($result);
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
$i=0;

while( $i < $num) {
$user = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i, "user"));
$todayscore = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i, "todayscore"));

echo '
'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i, "user")).' 
'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i, "todayscore ")).' points
<br/>';

$i++;
    }   
    }}
```

This results in a list like this:
User two 200 points
User one 300 points
User two 150 points
User two 100 points

Now I would like it to summarize like this (from the example above):
User two 450 points
User one 300 points

And if possible, arange so that the user with the most points gets on top the others.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(todayscore) AS points, user FROM list WHERE date = curdate() GROUP BY user ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: Great, that works super. I got one more question. I would also like to add how many times the user has played the game. For example:
User two 450 points. Played 4 times.
User one 300 points. Played 4 times.

the value on how many times a user has played is stored on the column played with the word played.
How can I add this to your code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really brush up on some basic database knowledge. :) I don't understand what you mean by "column" / "word".